# Radiobutton List in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am using a Radio Button List in my app with 2 options. In the page, it is displayed in 2 different lines(one below the other). Can we display it in a single line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `RepeatDirection` property to of the `radiobuttonlist' to`"Horizontal"`

```
<asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal " runat="server">
Some Content
</asp:RadioButtonList >
```

By default, RepeatDirection is set to Vertical. Setting this property to Horizontal will render the list horizontally.

[MSDN Refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k30eyz%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)